# Elasticsearch and JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8, ElasticSearch and JQuery Datatables. I have 8.000 data in my elasticsearch. I am taking this datas and refresh with `setInterval` per 10 seconds. However, when refreshed Datatables return me error and crome give me error. Crome error: `[Violation] 'load' handler took <N>ms`.